# Problems with Media gallery

Tags: 7, media

I am using the media-gallery module to create dynamic galleries for a site.
I have a problem when I edit a node; I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: media_gallery_format in locale_field_node_form_submit() (linea 405)

I have read [Undefined indexes in locale_field_node_form_submit()](http://drupal.org/node/1029486), but I didn't resolve the problem. The issue report suggests that the error depends from a local language, and that I should change one line in media-gallery.module, but I don't understand where that line is, and how to change the code.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The solution reported in the issue report is to replace any occurrence of `unset($form[$id])` with `$form[$id] = array('#language' => NULL)` in the module file; it just a matter of doing a "search and replace" on a file. What do you exactly don't understand?

Comment: Thank you kiamlaluno!! I dont understand where can i replace that string (problebly in media-gallery.module in line? ), sorry for my english...

Comment: Sorry kiamlaluno but i must replace all strings in "function media_gallery_form_media_gallery_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)" with occurence "unset($form[$id])" with "$form[$id] = array('#language' => NULL)" ?

Comment: See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution reported in the issue report is to replace every occurrence of `unset($form[$id])` with `$form[$id] = array('#language' => NULL)` in all the module file; you just search for the first string, and you replace it with the second string. The module file is media_gallery.module.
Who suggests the fix doesn't report in which line you find `unset($form[$id])` because you probably find more occurrences of that string, and the user doesn't want to make a list of all the lines containing that string. It is also useless to make such list, as an editor can easily make a search and replace for the strings listed in the issue report.